# PDFs are rendering fine, but printing with jagged edges - PDFSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, printing, pdfsharp

I have a complex application producing PDFs via PDFSharp. I'm running into a problem which is proving very difficult to solve.

When rendering images (text is an image as well) rotated, the PDF produced looks fine, but when printed it has jagged edges and generally messed up -- see attachment.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// determine how big the image should be
double destinationWidth = Math.Round(pageWidth * imageInfo.WidthFactor);
double destinationHeight = destinationWidth;

// rescale the image to needed size
imageInfo.Image = ImageHelper.ResizeImage(imageInfo.Image, (int)(destinationWidth * 3), (int)(destinationHeight * 3));

// get image
XImage xImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(imageInfo.Image);

// define fill area
XRect destination = new XRect();
destination.X = imageInfo.XFactor * pageWidth;
destination.Y = imageInfo.YFactor * pageHeight;
destination.Width = destinationWidth; //pageWidth * imageInfo.WidthFactor;
destination.Height = destinationHeight; //destination.Width; // shouldn't this use the page height and height factor?

// save state before rotate
XGraphicsState previousState = gfx.Save();

// rotate canvas
gfx.RotateAtTransform(imageInfo.RotationAngle, new XPoint(destination.X + destination.Width / 2, destination.Y + destination.Height / 2));

// render image
gfx.DrawImage(xImage, destination);

// undo transforms
gfx.Restore(previousState);
```

Please, please, help. It prints fine from Chrome's PDF viewer, for what it's worth.

I attempted converting the images to SVG (pixel by pixel) and rendering, which worked fine, but performance made it not feasible. I need to find a more elegant solution.

Thanks so much!

PDF:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49564994/PDF.pdf

Print-out:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49564994/Print.jpg

Comment: Are you printing from Acrobat Reader/Pro, or are you using another application?

Comment: The PDF link returns corrupt data.

Comment: I could retrieve both, the PDF as well as the JPEG just fine. However, before I'm trying to answer the question, I need to know: *How did you create the JPEG from the PDF?*

Comment: The JPEG is a printed page scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Almost two years ago I had a similar problem. A generated PDF was all garbled up when I printed it. It was just a report, did not contain any images, but several sentences or words were missing.

I used a Word template, replaced some placeholders to generate a report and then saved the Word document to PDF using the Office [Save As PDF add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9943).

There is a difference when you print the PDF with a PCL printer driver or a PostScript one. Check out if you get any difference between those. Might be a font problem. Check that the font encoding is set correctly.

At the time I did not find a solution. Finally resorted to converting the PDF to an image and sending that to the printer. Worked fine.

This should also be possible using PDFSharp by [invoking GhostScript to create images from PDF pages](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Can_PDFsharp_show_PDF_files_Print_PDF_files_Create_images_from_PDF_files_3).

Comment: I found no elegant solution. I created a transparent image the size of the PDF, rendered all images on it, then rendered it to the PDF. It sidesteps the rotation.